# SoapUI MockService - how to handle simultaneous requests?

Tags: web-services, mocking, soapui

How can I assure my SoapUI MockService will return the correct answer to the correct request? The response itself is generated inside the MockService script "OnRequest" and stored in property -

```
context.content
```

The content of the response is only

```
${content}
```

But if two or more requests happen at the same time both scripts get excuted at the same time and the response is not always correct because of the reassignment of the property.

Maybe - can I somehow synchronize executions of the script so that only one of them is running at the same time?

Comment: Not sure if you still have the issue. But how did you test it simultaneously?

Comment: With SoapUI's load test feature, by using several threads you can configure it so that two requests get sent at the same time

Comment: But have you put some assertion to know if the same mock response is sent for different requests? By the way, did you get around to this problem?

Comment: I coded the mock service to create logs. In the "AfterRequest" script I saved the MockResponse.getResponseContent() to a file

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch responses on some criteria in request, for ex.:

```
def postcode =  new XmlParser().parseText(postcodes[0].xmlText()).text()

if (postcode == "abcd") {return "response 1"}

else if (postcode == "efgh") {return "response 2"}
```

Comment: Hey, the issue is not selecting the right response, but rather that simultaneous requests overwrite each other's responses and all of them get the exact same response to different requests. This only happens if the recieved requests are on the same millisecond or so!

Answer (score 0):

In your case mock context is the object that needs to be synchronized. please check weather it got synchronized or not . when two threads[requests to mock] accessing at the same time . they both manipulate the same context at same time . hence context is the object you need to synchronize.

Comment: But how can I synchronize it? The keyword `Synchronized` and the annotiation do not work.

Comment: Try sending the context  object to a java call  and in java try handling that .